# double hyphens in `\SIrange` when used in math mode

Tags: siunitx

I am experiencing a strange behaviour of `\SIrange` in math mode:
If I have in text:

```
\SIrange{600}{620}{\celsius}
```

it gives
[image]

but if it is:

```
$\SIrange{600}{620}{\celsius}$
```

it gives:
[image]

Is it just me or is there a bug?

Comment: Could you please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? I get a different output.

Comment: you probably some where determine `range-phrase={ -- } `. this  is in math environment convert to to two minus signs. i would consider this as bug in `siunitx`. range phrase should stay in text mode.

Comment: Does the provided answer solve your problem? If yes, consider accepting it (this is normal in this community). The same is true for your other questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Zarko that the “range phrase” should be typeset as text also in math mode. Here's an example, the last `\sisetup` shows how to properly define the “range phrase” so it doesn't give unexpected results when in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Text: \SIrange{600}{620}{\celsius}

Math: $\SIrange{600}{620}{\celsius}$

\sisetup{range-phrase=--} % not so good

Text: \SIrange{600}{620}{\celsius}

Math: $\SIrange{600}{620}{\celsius}$

\sisetup{range-phrase=\textup{--}} % better

Text: \SIrange{600}{620}{\celsius}

Math: $\SIrange{600}{620}{\celsius}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to use `range-phrase=\textup{--}` as package option when loading `siunitx`, e.g. `\usepackage[range-phrase=\textup{--}]{siunitx}`, but I get errors like `Missing \endcsname inserted.`. Do you have any idea how to avoid this? Using `\sisetup{range-phrase=\textup{--}}` after loading the package works fine.